How to Optimize API Calls for Metadata and Component Rendering in Next.js 14 Src Directory
import PlatformComponent from "../Components/PlatformComponent";

async function fetchPlatformData(platform) {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/fetchPlatformData?platform=${platform}`);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch platform data');
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  const { platform } = params;

  const platformData = await fetchPlatformData(platform);

  return {
    title: `Search - The AdHunt | ${platformData.type}`,
    description: `${platformData.type} - ${platformData.short_description}`,
  };
}

export default async function Page({ params }) {
  const { platform } = params;

  const platformData = await fetchPlatformData(platform);

  return (
    <>
      <PlatformComponent data={platformData} />
    </>
  );
}


How can I optimize this setup to avoid making the API call twice? Is there a way to share the fetched data between generateMetadata and the Page component to improve performance and efficiency?
The fetchPlatformData function is called twice: once in generateMetadata for setting the page metadata, and once in the Page component for rendering.
